# How to get the total number of visits by the people who are not logged in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

So i want to see some stats in my admin dashboard for ex the total number of users (which is easy to do) and also the total number of website visits by everyone (logged in & users) and also total number of visits(people who are not logged in)?
New in Laravel.

Have not Tried it jet.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to make a table for your dashboard that save the informations. If you still didn't created one, see the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations).

Then, you can make new middleware with this command `php artisan make:middleware CountVisits`

App\Http\Middleware\CountVisits.php:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    //Get the first row that contain the dashboard information
    $dashboard = Dashboard::where('id', 1)->first(); 
    
    //Get the current visits counter
    $counter = $dashboard->visits_counter;
    $updated_counter = $counter++;

    //Update the field
    $dashbord->update([
                     'visits_counter' => $updated_counter
        ]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

This will set a field of `visits_coutner` to the updated counter given. this field must exists in your migration.

**App\Http\Kernel.php:**

```
protected $middleware = [

    (...)

    \App\Http\Middleware\CountVisits::class,
];
```

This will register the middleware to be applied globally to each route.

Comment: Adding it to the kernel registers the middleware to fire on each route. If you want to add them manually, skip this step and include it on the routes you want it on. If you want to exclude only specific routes, you can use the ->withoutMiddleware(...) function on the route